# i need help to show this data in android app

Tags: java, android, json

```
{
  "widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
      "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
      "name": "main_window",
      "width": 500,
      "height": 500
    },
    "image": {
      "src": "Images/Sun.png",
      "name": "sun1",
      "hOffset": 250,
      "vOffset": 250,
      "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
      "data": "Click Here",
      "size": 36,
      "style": "bold",
      "name": "text1",
      "hOffset": 250,
      "vOffset": 100,
      "alignment": "center",
      "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: android studio using httpurl connection

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not here to write code for you . Mention specifically where you are having  problem .

Comment: This answer has some good examples for what you want to achieve: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9606629/991200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a JSON object array so first you have to get the `widget` JSON object and then from the tag(value) of "window" get the inner JSON array. from that get the other objects.

```
{ "widget": 
{ "debug": "on", 
"window": 
    { "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget", "name": "main_window", "width": 500, "height": 500 }, 
"image": { "src": "Images/Sun.png", "name": "sun1", "hOffset": 250, "vOffset": 250, "alignment": "center" },
"text": { "data": "Click Here", "size": 36, "style": "bold", "name": "text1", "hOffset": 250, "vOffset": 100, "alignment": "center", "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;" } 
} 
}
```

Refer a tutorial on how to manipulate JSON objects in Android.

have fun coding.

Answer (score 0):

First, create your Models to parsing this JSON array. you can use [JsonUtils](http://jsonutils.com/) and other JSON online tools to generate your models.

Then you have to use some tools to parsing (deserialize) JSON into your models. GSON is one of this tools. finally, you can get your data from your models and set them into the views.

Comment: Thanx FarshidABZ